# Highcharts: Column and Bar Chart labels are incorrect when I drilldown

Tags: highcharts, highcharts-ng

I am using highcharts-ng. In column and bar charts of highcharts, if the data set is large, the x-axis is being plot as random numbers instead of the given category.

If I deselect and select the legend, then the x-axis labels appear correctly.

```
    $scope.chartConfig = {
      options: {
        chart: {
          type: "bar"
        }
      },
      xAxis: {
        type: "category",
        title: {
          text: "country"
        }
        //tickInterval: 30          
      },
      // series with over 184 data points
      series: [
        {
          name: "values",
          data: [
            {
              name: "Afghanistan",
              y: 66.48275862068965
            },
            {
              name: "Aland Islands",
              y: 49
            },
            {
              name: "Albania",
              y: 49.42424242424242
            },


          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

[here's a fiddle with the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/dilani_di/2554kx8x/6/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[It is a Highcharts bug. Already reported [here](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/5857).

In version 4.2.6 the issue does not show up. https://jsfiddle.net/m0jbh333/

Also you could try using the newest version with set cropTreshold - it seems that it works as well. https://jsfiddle.net/m0jbh333/1/

```
series: [
          {
          turboThreshold: 0,
          cropThreshold: 500,
```